# How to reposition an UITextField to a specific position with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield, constraints

I am creating a view on swift 4.0 for IOS. I have 5 UITextField like on my example. I want to change the position of "tf5" and place it between "tf2" and "tf3" but i can't use margin top on Auto Layout. I tried to define constraits like other solutions but can't solve this problem so far. How can i achieve this? Thanks for your helps.

[image]

Comment: Use tableview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want it programmatically, here's a version with `UIStackView`:

```
let tf1 = UITextField()
let tf2 = UITextField()
let tf3 = UITextField()
let tf4 = UITextField()
let tf5 = UITextField()

let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .fill
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.spacing = 8

// this arranges them from 1 to 5
stackView.addArrangedSubview(tf1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(tf2)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(tf3)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(tf4)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(tf5)

// now you just need to use autolayout to position the stackview properly, and it will take
// care of textFields for you

// now if you want to place tf5 before tf3 later
let indexOfTF3 = stackView.arrangedSubviews.index(of: tf3)!
stackView.insertArrangedSubview(tf5, at: indexOfTF3)
// or you can use number 2 instead of indexOfTF3, since in this case we know that it is there
```

Sidenote: you can use the same `stackView` to position also `tw1` `UITextView`, but if I remember correctly, you would have to add a constraint to determine its height (since it does not have intrinsic size) for the `.fill` distribution of `stackView` to work properly.

Comment: Thank you but i want to ask another question. Can i create and add just a new UITextField between any of them instead of changing it's position?

Answer (score 0):

The [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) component would be useful in your case. What you could do is add all of the fields into a -vertical- stack view:

Select all of the desired text fields/text views and click on "Embed in Stack" button:

[image]

Thus it would should be displayed in the document outline area as:

[image]

Simply, at this point all you have to do is to drag any of the text field and change its position:

[image]

Therefor you should set the appropriate constraints for the new created stack view. and -obviously- its properties such as the spacing between the fields (you could do it in the IB).

Comment: I want to do it programmatically, i mean with code.

Comment: @YunusEmreMeral then you could add a table view and consider that each field represents a cell.